# ui-router demo project not working with components

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, bower

wanting to use state based routing I tried the sample project from ui-router here:

[ui-router demo](https://ui-router.github.io/tutorial/ng1/hellosolarsystem)

It works, but only as long as this reference to the pre-release library is made:

```js
    <!-- working -->
    <script src="//npmcdn.com/angular-ui-router@1.0.0-alpha.4/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

If I install the most recent version, components are not injected into the demo view project anymore. It simply fails without error.

```js
    <!-- not working -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

I installed the library using bower like this - with and without specific version:

bower install angular-ui-router#0.3.1 --save

I also tried install using npm like this:

npm install --save angular-ui-router

The demo project simply does not work with these libraries. Was there any breaking change or what wents wrong?

Regards!

Comment: `0.3.1` is the latest stable version, but it doesn't support `component`. This feature was introduced in `1.0.0` - see [CHANGELOG.MD](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100-alpha1-commits-2016-03-27)

Comment: Ah, that's it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there have been breaking changes since I have been using ui-router heavily since the past one year.
Check whether your bower_components falls inside a static directory. If you haven't configured it to, and if you're on node+express, you can write something like

```
app.use(express.static('client'));
```

What this does is it will make node (I'm assuming you're on node) server all files in this directory to the public. Kind of like the directory directives you use in apache (if you have) to give public access to all *these* files under this/that folder.

Optional Tip:
bower_components just looks ugly. make a `.bowerrc` file under the same directory where your `server.js` lives and type this in it:

```
{
  "directory":"client/assets/lib"
}
```

What this will do is (from now on) install all dependencies under lib folder. Of course your path may be different but I like the structure it this way. But make sure you put this directory under the static directory (client in this example);

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Amin,

you are right. There was no breaking change. In fact, it never worked using the production release. See comment from MiTa.